# How access path from digital camera C#

Tags: c#, path, directory, relative-path, file-copying

C#

I need to copy a file on an Android device (Not have mass storage option, `KitKat 4.4)` to desktop in Windows, which appears not listed as an `absolute path (H: \\ J: \\ ... etc)`, but appears as `"My Computer\SM-T531\Tablet\ database .db"`

```
string sourceDir = @My Computer\SM-T531\Tablet\";
string destinationDir = @Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/DataBases";
DirectoryInfo dirSource = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetFullPath(sourceDir));
DirectoryInfo dirDestination = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetFullPath(destinationDir));

foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.db"))                                                                
{
    File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(destinationDir, Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
}
```

so... the problem is that the source path not found

How can resolved this ?

Comment: here is a hint.. use the `Debugger` and step through the code placing `breakpoints` on ever line also does the path really have those spaces in it ..? I doubt it but just wondering.

Comment: yes, but says "the source path not exist"...

Comment: Is not a logical unit "E:, H:" etc..